# IllegalAccessError for RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider while launching Apache Twill Application in hadoop cluster after HDP upgrade

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, apache-twill

I'm trying to launch Apache Twill application from hadoop cluster, the cluster is recently upgraded from HDP 2.2 to HDP 2.5 but I'm getting llegalAccessError for RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider class . This class is part of org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client package. I'm getting this error in the Application Master. The job status goes directy to 'not running state' right after 'accepted state'.

```
Exception in thread "Hadoop22YarnAMClient STARTING" Exception in thread "YarnAMClientService STARTING" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider.getProxyInternal()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider.init(RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMFailoverProxyProvider(RMProxy.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMProxy(RMProxy.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ClientRMProxy.createRMProxy(ClientRMProxy.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.serviceStart(AMRMClientImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
at org.apache.twill.internal.yarn.Hadoop21YarnAMClient.startUp(Hadoop21YarnAMClient.java:77)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$1$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:43)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider.getProxyInternal()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1008)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1001)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAndWait(AbstractService.java:220)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService.startAndWait(AbstractIdleService.java:106)
at org.apache.twill.internal.appmaster.ApplicationMasterMain$YarnAMClientService.startUp(ApplicationMasterMain.java:221)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$1$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:43)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider.getProxyInternal()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider.init(RequestHedgingRMFailoverProxyProvider.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMFailoverProxyProvider(RMProxy.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy.createRMProxy(RMProxy.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.ClientRMProxy.createRMProxy(ClientRMProxy.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.serviceStart(AMRMClientImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
at org.apache.twill.internal.yarn.Hadoop21YarnAMClient.startUp(Hadoop21YarnAMClient.java:77)
... 2 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general when you see `IllegalAccessError` this means you have a runtime incompatibility between compiled and runtime code.  In this case, 
the `getProxyInternal()` method of `ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider` is now private.  You need to recompile your client code and/or use updated hadoop client libraries to connect to your cluster.

Comment: I updated the build.gradle file to have hadoop version 2.7.3 from 2.4.0 and it solved it :)